# How to fix "Failed to pull image" on microk8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s

Im trying to follow the get started docker's tutorials, but I get stuck when you have to work with kuberetes. I'm using microk8s to create the clusters.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.11.5WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

My bb.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bb-demo
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      bb: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        bb: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bb-site
        image: bulletinboard:1.0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bb-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    bb: web
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30001
```

I create the image with

```
docker image build -t bulletinboard:1.0 .
```

And I create the pod and the service with:

```
microk8s.kubectl apply -f bb.yaml
```

The pod is created, but, when I look for the state of my pods with

```
microk8s.kubectl get all
```

It says:

```
NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/bb-demo-7ffb568776-6njfg   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          11m

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/bb-entrypoint   NodePort    10.152.183.2   <none>        8080:30001/TCP   11m
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.152.183.1   <none>        443/TCP          4d

NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/bb-demo   0/1     1            0           11m

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/bb-demo-7ffb568776   1         1         0       11m
```

Also, when I look for it at the kubernetes dashboard it says:

Failed to pull image "bulletinboard:1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image "docker.io/library/bulletinboard:1.0": no available registry endpoint: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

**Q: Why do I get this error? Im just following the tutorial without skipping anything.**

Im already logged with docker.

Comment: Can you pull the image locally, are you sure it exist? `docker pull docker.io/library/bulletinboard:1.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to push this locally built image to the Docker Hub registry. For that, you need to create a Docker Hub account if you do not have one already.

Once you do that, you need to login to Docker Hub from your command line.

`docker login`

Tag your image so it goes to your Docker Hub repository.

`docker tag bulletinboard:1.0 <your docker hub user>/bulletinboard:1.0`

Push your image to Docker Hub

`docker push <your docker hub user>/bulletinboard:1.0`

Update the yaml file to reflect the new image repo on Docker Hub.

`spec:
      containers:
      - name: bb-site
        image: <your docker hub user>/bulletinboard:1.0`

re-apply the yaml file

`microk8s.kubectl apply -f bb.yaml`

Answer (score 4):

You can host a local registry server if you do not wish to use Docker hub.

1. Start a local registry server:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

2. Tag your image:

```
sudo docker tag bulletinboard:1.0 localhost:5000/bulletinboard
```

3. Push it to a local registry:

```
sudo docker push localhost:5000/bulletinboard
```

4. Change the `yaml` file:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: bb-site
        image: localhost:5000/bulletinboard
```

5. Start deployment

```
kubectl apply -f bb.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

A suggested solution is to add `imagePullPolicy: Never` to your Deployment as per the answer [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/704) but this didn't work for me, so I followed [this](https://blog.payara.fish/what-is-kubernetes) guide since I was working in local development.