# Can't access container's port in microk8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, microk8s

Trying to run container in `microk8s`.

According to https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/ , after deploy the service.

`microk8s.kubectl get services` shows:

```
   NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
   bb-entrypoint      NodePort    10.152.183.182   <none>        8080:30001/TCP   5m51s
   kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP          35d
   microbot-service   NodePort    10.152.183.80    <none>        80:31223/TCP     19
```

But, I can't access the `bb-entrypoint` service via any of following address:

- `localhost:30001`
- `10.152.183.182:8080`

The os is `mint mate` based on (`ubuntu`), and I have disabled `ufw`.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for this to be debuggable: where are you making this call from, what specific error are you getting, and what YAML files are you using to define the deployment and service objects?  This could be caused by making the HTTP call from the wrong place, or the pod and service labels not matching up, or the pod just not starting up, or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure whether endpoints are created for this service or not by running kubectl get ep
In this case i'm seeing endpoints are not created because the pod was having issues in pulling the image from docker and so it i not in ready status

```
[root@master tmp]# kubectl get ep
NAME            ENDPOINTS           AGE
bb-entrypoint                       9m24s

[root@master tmp]# kubectl get po
NAME                         READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
bb-demo-7ffb568776-q6xs2     0/1     ImagePullBackOff             0          9m55s

Warning  Failed          6h15m (x3 over 6h17m)   kubelet, node1.k8s  Failed to pull image "bulletinboard:1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = repository docker.io/bulletinboard not found: does not exist or no pull access
  Warning  Failed          6h15m (x3 over 6h17m)   kubelet, node1.k8s  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff         6h15m (x7 over 6h17m)   kubelet, node1.k8s  Back-off pulling image "bulletinboard:1.0"
  Normal   Pulling         6h14m (x4 over 6h17m)   kubelet, node1.k8s  Pulling image "bulletinboard:1.0"
  Warning  Failed          6h12m (x15 over 6h17m)  kubelet, node1.k8s  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631155/how-to-fix-failed-to-pull-image-on-microk8s . After login to docker, and push the image to docker.io, then pull from remote instead would fix it.